# Question on python xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

How to know the total number of columns used in an excel sheet in the following link
http://scienceoss.com/read-excel-files-from-python/

Thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Sheet` class has a `ncols` member which indicates the number of columns

Comment: i would have accepted it when i wrote the comment.But stackoverflow imposes some timimg constraints to accept the answer:)

Answer (score 8):

Here are the first 6 lines in the "Quick Start" section of xlrd's README.html:

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("myfile.xls")
print "The number of worksheets is", book.nsheets
print "Worksheet name(s):", book.sheet_names()
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
print sh.name, sh.nrows, sh.ncols
```

You can get a tutorial via [this link](http://www.python-excel.org/). Likewise the latest SVN commit of the docs. If you installed xlrd from a source distribution or by running a Windows installer, you should already have the docs.